# How can I add hard returns via Excel::Writer::XLSX?

Tags: perl, xlsx

Should be simple but hard to google: how to get hard returns (as in Excel's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) within text inserted into a .xlsx spreadsheet via perl module [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX)?

Answer (score 3):

Add the "\n" to the string, and adjust the format.

(see the doc: https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_text_wrap)

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_text_wrap(); # essential for correct "look" in Excel.
$worksheet->write( "B2", "Hi\nExcel!", $format );
                            ^^
```

Comment: I have found that when viewing with LibreOffice, the presence of `set_text_wrap` makes no difference. When viewing with Office on MacOS, it needs to be there for the line breaks to work.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX), you just put in a newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );

# Add a worksheet
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my ($row, $col) = (0, 0);
$worksheet->write($row, $col, "Hi Excel!\nHi, again!");

$workbook->close;
```

Most of this is based directly off the documentation.